# R: package ‘arulesViz’ is not available (as a binary package for R version 3.1.3)

Tags: r, package

I'm a newcomer in R and studying Apriori algorithm now.

The problem is I can install the R package `arules` but when I want to install the package `arulesViz`, R is throwing an error message:

> install.packages("arulesViz")
>
> package ‘arulesViz’ is available as a source package but not as a binary
>
> Warning in install.packages :
>
> package ‘arulesViz’ is not available (as a binary package for R version 3.1.3)

I have read the article "How should I deal with “package 'xxx' is not available” warning?", but I still don't understand how to solve this problem.

Comment: Microsoft Windows 8~~

Comment: What is the mirror you used? Also, you should upgrade your version of R.

Comment: @Pascal Thank you!!!!
I'm able to install the package「arulesViz」 
after upgrading my version of R !!!
Apparently it's the problem of version.

Answer (score 1):

If your OS is Microsoft Windows and you have Rtools (http://cran.revolutionanalytics.com/bin/windows/Rtools/) installed, then you can do the following:

```
install.packages("arulesViz", type = "source")
```

Comment: This is useless. `arulesViz` is available as a binary for Windows: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arulesViz/index.html